# Retrieve Facebook users tagged information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good Day!
I am trying to retrieve a Facebook user tagged information. Currently I am using Facebook Graph API to retrieve user wall information using USER_ID and APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

Is there any way in Facebook Graph API (or anyother API's) through which I can retrieve the users tagged detail? I have only app access token (but not the user access token).

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me a solution. Thank you again.

Comment: I am still searching for a solution. Can anyone please suggest me whether it is possible to retrieve Facebook users tagged information by using USER_ID and APP_ACCESS_TOKEN? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is `/USER_ID/tagged` what you're looking for?  Try it in [the graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=NewRepublicBrewing/tagged).